# .NET MySql connector utf8 issue

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

My schema, table and varchar columns have a collation `utf8 - utf8_turkish_ci` and I am trying to insert turkish specific characters into a varchar(200) column.

My query is like below

```
insert into categories (name) values ('ışığı')
```

When I execute this query via MySql Workbench everything is fine.

But when I execute this query using MySqlClient `ışığı` is inserted as `isigi`. Somehow turkish charaters are get lost.

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into categories (name) values ('ışığı')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I also tried executing `SET NAMES UTF8` before insert but it did not work.

NOTE: I do not have access to mysql configuration files, only MySql Workbench.

Comment: Have you specified `CharSet=utf8` in connection string?